# wordpress stripping out apostrophes in the_title

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running the Wordpress loop and when I display `the_title()` it is stripping out all apostrophes...

Something that says `Matt's Books` is displaying as `Matts Books`.

I've done some research looking into the formatting.php, post-template.php, and other pages as well as the codex and haven't been able to come across an answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

The answer to this was to simply comment out around line 103 of wp-includes/default-filters.php:

```
// Default Filters
// add_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize'   ); /*comment out this line */
```

Comment: If you're going to write about apostrophes, you should first understand what they are. I have fixed your question title and body.

Answer (score 3):

### [Hacking WordPress Core](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1639/what-are-some-reasons-why-you-should-not-hack-wordpress-core-files) is NEVER a good idea.

The wptexturize filter converts characters to their proper HTML entity.  If it's not converting apostrophe characters correctly there could be a character encoding setting problem or most likely an issue with the theme your using.

What is your character encoding set to in settings - reading settings?

If you want to remove the wptexturize filter the proper way is to add this to your functions.php

```
remove_filter ('the_title', 'wptexturize');
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it could be issue with the particular theme you're using.

Try putting html code `&#39;` in place of apostrophe.

Also take a look at this blog post related to the same problem: http://takethu.com/blog/2006/09/01/wordpress-curlification-of-apostrophe-in-title/

Comment: @anubhava, may I ask you to have a look at a wordpress custom field related question here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782429/wordpress-make-custom-field-values-clickable-to-retrive-them-later ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo the title of the website like this:

```
<title><?php echo "Someone's Website" ?></title>
```

It will not escape apostrophe.